# Using built-in datetime function in a class in python

Tags: python

I need help on how to use the datetime function with inheritance implementation of a class. I seriously don't know why i'm getting an this error beneath the block of code:

```
import datetime
class Estate():
    namelist = []
    def __init__(self, name, car_number, EntryDate):
        self.name = name
        self.car_number = car_number
        assert type(EntryDate) == datetime.date
        self.EntryDate == EntryDate
        Estate.namelist.append(self.name)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_number(self):
        return self.car_number

class ThreeBedroom(Estate):
    def __init__(self, name, car_number, rent):
        Estate.__init__(self, name, car_number)
        self.rent = rent

    def set_rent(self):
        self.rent = rent

class twoBedroom(Estate):
    def __init__(self, name, car_number, EntryDate, rent):
        Estate.__init__(self, name, car_number, EntryDate)
        self.rent = rent
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


Tenant1 = twoBedroom("Amadi", 44557, datetime.date(2012, 12, 27), 350000)
print Estate.namelist
```

Here is the exception--

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Estate.py", line 31, in 
    Tenant1 = twoBedroom("Amadi", 44557, datetime.date(2012, 12, 27), 350000)
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined

Comment: Did you mean to do assignment `=` instead of equality comparision `==` here: `self.EntryDate == EntryDate`? Also, there's no attribute `lis` for `Estate`...

Comment: are you sure you have `import datetime` at the top?

Answer (score 1):

You should be assigning  not comparing equality:

```
self.EntryDate = EntryDate
```

and it is `print Estate.namelist` there is no attribute `print Estate.lis`

You are also trying to set rent like `self.rent = rent`, rent does not exist

```
def set_rent(self):
    self.rent = rent
```

You could use a method where rent is passed in:

```
 def set_rent(self,rent):
        self.rent = rent
```

But it is easier to just access the attribute the attribute directly`self.rent`

In `class ThreeBedroom` you do not have `EntryDate` included in the init method.

```
class ThreeBedroom(Estate):
    def __init__(self, name, car_number,EntryDate, rent):
        Estate.__init__(self, name, car_number,EntryDate)
```

The code then runs fine:

```
In [2]: Tenant1 = twoBedroom("Amadi", 44557, datetime.date(2012, 12, 27), 350000)

In [3]: Tenant2 = ThreeBedroom("Amadi", 44557, datetime.date(2012, 12, 27), 350000)

In [4]: Estate.namelist
Out[4]: ['Amadi', 'Amadi']
```

Comment: @padriac Thanks for helping me out on this one. It has worked just fine.

Comment: @user3566502 If Padraic's answer fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/204922) for a full explanation.